# Jquery function never running on the first instance it is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I am trying to create a submit button that will submit when the user presses the enter key.

I am having to click the submit button once, before I can use the enter button as a 'virtual click'.

If I try to use the enter key to submit straight away, it won't do it, the first press has to be with the mouse.
What is causing this bug?

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6tk92stn/)

```js
$("#guessSubmit").keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
  $("#guessSubmit").click();
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" id="guessSubmit" onclick=alert("test")>
```

Comment: Another thing to note is that when you click it and press enter it only does so if you don't click elsewhere. So the button is still 'selected' when you press enter.

Comment: Try to assign `keydown` to your form or parent element?

Comment: Why not bind keydown event to `document` or `body`?

Comment: He may have several forms on page..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't add keypress on the button, but on the body or the window.

```
$(document.body).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#guessSubmit").click();
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/baz6bqmw/)

Comment: @TobyCannon make sure to mark this as an answer then. ;)

Comment: Upvoted, have to wait for the SO timer to mark as answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `autofocus` property:

```js
$("#guessSubmit").keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#guessSubmit").click();
        return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" id="guessSubmit" onclick='alert("test")' autofocus>
```

Answer (score 1):

The button will only receive key events when it is in focus. You can programmatically set the focus like so:

```
$("#guessSubmit").focus();
```

UPDATE: But there is a much better way to handle the 13 key: put your button in a form. The form will be submitted whenever an enter key is pressed and the focus is on any input element in the form:
HTML:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="text" autofocus />
    <input type="submit" id="guessSubmit" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#myform").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("test");
});
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/robbyn/62vnrcde/

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue and it was to do with focus.
I had to set the current focus to the element.  It works with the mouse because that sets focus.

Here is an updated code

```
//Submits if enter key is pressed
            $("#guessSubmit").keydown(function(event){
                if(event.keyCode == 13){
                    $("#guessSubmit").click();
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });

$("#guessSubmit").focus();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6tk92stn/

Answer (score 0):

If you force focus on the button it should work?

```
$("#guessSubmit").focus().keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#guessSubmit").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: This should work, but I don't think it's the best way to do it.

Comment: I think it is an issue of focus. Because the button isn't focused when you load the page, the enter won't be linked to anything. Out of interest, why don't you think this is the best way to do it?

Comment: Well actually I'm not sure it would even work.. Since you're calling a focus event but there's no event to trigger that other than the page load?

It would make more sense to call the keydown on the page in my opinion, or on keydown for any of the form fields.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0vzafuhg/ Maybe I'm missing something but it doesn't seem to work for me?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check keycode on document click like following:

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
                if(event.keyCode === 13){
                    $("#guessSubmit").click();
                }
            });
```

Check [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/6tk92stn/2/)